# ColdFusion FTP Explicit TLS

Tags: coldfusion, ftp, ftps

Is it possible to do a ColdFusion FTP connection using Explicit TLS?

I have searched on Google but to no avail.

Comment: Did you try? If so and it did not work, what error did you get? Are you asking about using the `cfftp` tag? What version of ColdFusion are you running? On what operating system? We need some more information to help you but I would say the first step is to just try it and see what happens. If it fails then post back with what you tried and how it failed. [Here are the docs for cfftp and secure connections](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-72fa.html).

Answer (score 3):

The Apache Commons has an [FTPSClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html) class as well, and I think it is already available in the later versions of Coldfusion.

Just adding an example.  It uses a test server that I found available.  I am using CF 9.0.2, and did not have to download any additional jars.

```
ftpsClient = CreateObject("java","org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient").init(JavaCast("boolean",true));
ftpsClient.connect(JavaCast("string","ftp.secureftp-test.com"),990);
connected = ftpsClient.isConnected();

WriteOutput("Is Connected:" &  connected & '<br/>');

login = ftpsClient.login('test','test');
WriteOutput("Is Logged in:" &  login & '<br/>');


ftpsClient.logout();
ftpsClient.disconnect();
connected = ftpsClient.isConnected();

WriteOutput("Is Connected:" &  connected & '<br/>');
```

Comment: The test server I am using in this code is no longer available, but I setup my own local server for testing

Answer (score 1):

Unless something changed in CF10, `CFFTP` supports `secure FTP` but not `SFTP` or `FTPS`. You may need to use a java library like [`FTP4J`](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/index.php) as mentioned in [this blog](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/coldfusion-and-ftp-over-implicit-tls-ssl-301).

From the [FTP4J documentation](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php#6):

> ***FTPS/FTPES secured connection***
>
> The ftp4j library supports both FTPS
>   (FTP over implicit TLS/SSL) and FTPES (FTP over explicit TLS/SSL).
>
> The setSecurity() method can be used to turn on the feature:
>
> client.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPS); // enables FTPS
>   **client.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES); // enables FTPES**

as Miguel-F pointed out, if you switch the comment on these two lines it should enable FTPES.

```
//FTPClient.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES); // enables FTPES
FTPClient.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPS); // enables FTPS
```

Comment: Since we gave the same answer, even referencing the same blog post, and you beat me by a few seconds I have deleted mine and up-voted yours.  Touche my friend...  ;)

Comment: nah, keep yours up, you reference the line of code you need to enable the ftpes.  I'll vote yours up too.

Comment: No biggie, just add the reference to yours. Thanks tho.