# ColdFusion Version 9 Secure FTP - Unable to Connect

Tags: coldfusion, ftp, sftp, coldfusion-9, ftps

I am looking to automate something that is currently being done manually.  The manual process is being performed using ftp client Filezilla.  These are the instructions:

```
In the Host field, type in the IP address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
In the Port field, type in 990.
In the Servertype dropdown list, change it so that it reads 
 FTP over SSL/TLS (implicit encryption). (NOTE: On the Mac OSX 
 version this option will read FTPS – FTP over implicit TLS/SSL).
In the Logontype area, select Normal.
In the Username field, enter your username.
In the Password field, enter your password.
```

When I follow those instructions, I connect successfully.   This is what I tried in ColdFusion:

```
<cfftp action="open"
connection="abc"
secure = true
server="something valid"
port="990"
username="something valid" 
password="something valid">
```

This is the error message:  `An error occurred while establishing an sFTP connection.  Verify your connection attributes: username, password, server, fingerprint, port, key, connection, proxyServer, and secure (as applicable). Error: Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.`

When I remove the port attibute, the result is unchanged.  When I change the username to something not valid, I get a slightly different error:  `An error occurred while establishing an sFTP connection.    Verify your connection attributes: username, password, server, fingerprint, port, key, connection, proxyServer, and secure (as applicable). Error: connection is closed by foreign host.`

In other words, the timeout is replaced by an intentional closure.

What should I be looking at in order to sort this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your creating a FTPS connection in Filezilla, and ColdFusion 9 doesn’t have native support for FTPS, only SFTP. Thanks to [abbottmw answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16588788/923833) I was able to create an Explicit FTPS connection in the past. ColdFusion 9 ships with the Apache Commons library and you can create the connection on the java level with [FTPSClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html).