# Secure FTP From ColdFusion 9 Using Java FTP Client

Tags: java, coldfusion, ftp, sftp

This is a followup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775022/coldfusion-version-9-secure-ftp-unable-to-connect).  The correct answer leads to an attempt to use the SFTPClient class in the Apache Commons library.

I can connect.  The next step is to upload a file.  There is a lot of reference material with sample source code.  I used [this one](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-upload-tutorial-and-example) as my guide.  It's not secure FTP, but it's simple to follow.  This is the java code I was attempting to emulate:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class FTPUploadFileDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "www.myserver.com";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "user";
        String pass = "pass";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            // This was considered unnecessary because I was sending n ASCII file

            // APPROACH #1: uploads first file using an InputStream
            File firstLocalFile = new File("D:/Test/Projects.zip");

            String firstRemoteFile = "Projects.zip";
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

            System.out.println("Start uploading first file");
            boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
and some more code that's not relevent,
```

This is my ColdFusion equivalent:

```
localFilename = "d:\dw\dwtest\dan\textfiles\randomText.txt"; 
remoteFileName = "randomText.txt";

javaFtpClient = CreateObject("java", 
  "org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient").init("SSL", JavaCast("boolean",true));
// note that I am using a secure client

 javaInputFile = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init(localFilename); 
 javaInputStream = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream").init(javaInputFile); 

// connect and login 
javaFtpClient.connect(JavaCast("string","something"),990); 
loginStatus = javaFtpClient.login('valid username','valid password');
writeoutput("login status " & loginStatus & "<br>"); 
javaFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();


uploadStatus = javaFtpClient.storeFile(remoteFileName, javaInputStream); 
writeOutput("upload status " & uploadStatus & "<br>"); javaInputStream.close();

// logout and disconnect 
javaFtpClient.logout(); 
javaFtpClient.disconnect();

writeoutput("done" & "<br>");
```

The output shows a successful login and an unsuccessful file upload.  The lack of file was confirmed using FileZilla.

Can anybody see why the file was not uploaded?

Comment: Do you have access to the FTP server's console/log? Also, does it throw an exception?

Comment: I don't have access, but I might know someone who does.  For the CF Code, given that the output includes "done", from the last `writeoutput` command, I assume there were no exceptions.  Also,  I did experience exceptions along the way.

Comment: I'ts a shot in the dark, but from my notes we had to set the `javaFtpClient.execPROT("P")` with the server we were working with. You may see something similar in your FileZilla console.

Comment: @Twillen, compliments on the accuracy of your shooting in the dark.  Addding `javaFtpClient.execPROT("P");` after 'javaFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();' solved the problem.  Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Twillen, aka "FTP sharpshooter" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `javaFtpClient.execProt("P")` is required. Setting PROT to "P" sets the Data Channel Protection Level to private.